# How to get the name of the updated columns in a trigger oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

I'm working in an Oracle Apex Application where the users get their information about their requested orders. The administrators can edit the information on the table and change the info of the orders and I need to keep a log of which columns where updated. I created a trigger after update but now I need to get the name of the columns that where edited in the Tabular Form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the trigger

```
IF UPDATING( 'column_name' )
```

will tell you whether the `update` statement actually updated a particular column.  Depending on how the application is built, however, it may well be updating every column whether or not there was actually a change.  If you are trying to account for that, you'd need to compare the `:new` and `:old` values.  If the columns are non-nullable

```
IF( :new.column_name != :old.column_name )
```

If you have to account for `null` values, it gets a bit more verbose

```
IF( :new.column_name != :old.column_name or
    (:new.column_name is null and :old.column_name is not null) or
    (:new.column_name is not null and :old.column_name is null) )
```

Comment: the OP could also create a trigger for each column, if there are only a few of them it could be easier to handle the code...

Comment: @Typo - You could, sure.  I'm not sure how that would be any easier to manage than a single trigger with a few very similar `IF` statements.  If you did that, however, you'd have the same issue that you have with a single trigger.  The `after update of <<column name>>` syntax behaves the same way that `if updating('<<column name>>')` does.  You could add a `when` clause to each trigger that compares `:new` to `:old` values but I don't see how that simplifies anything.

Comment: well, if it is a large table structure any update will trigger the code, which could bring efficiency concerns, plus you don't need to check if the column it's been updated, you know it is by definition. I'm just saying that it's another option to consider.

Comment: @Typo - If you want to limit yourself to firing only when certain columns are updated (whether or not the values actually change), it would still seem to make more sense to have a single trigger and just list out the columns in the `after update of` clause rather than having a bunch of triggers defined on the table.

Answer (score 0):

DESCRIPTION:
This code can be used for creating all if conditions for all Columns in the updated table:

here there are 2 Parts in the below solution:
Part1:
The query for creating the Part2(Trigger-Script)

Part2:
in the Script, the changed column is detected.
then the "V_COLS_UPDATED" will contain all columns that have been updated.
so you can insert this variable in the specified log column!

```
  

--- TRIGGER(BODY) SCRIPT SAMPLE :

    BEGIN
      -- IF_UPDATING
     IF UPDATING ('EMPLOYEE_ID') THEN V_COLS_UPDATED:=V_COLS_UPDATED || 'EMPLOYEE_ID' || ',' ; END IF;  
     IF UPDATING ('FIRST_NAME') THEN V_COLS_UPDATED:=V_COLS_UPDATED || 'FIRST_NAME' || ',' ; END IF;  
     
     -- IF_UPDATING_AND_CHECK_VALUES
     IF UPDATING ('EMPLOYEE_ID') AND NVL(:NEW.EMPLOYEE_ID,-1) != NVL(:OLD.EMPLOYEE_ID,-1)  THEN V_COLS_UPDATED:=V_COLS_UPDATED || 'EMPLOYEE_ID' || ',' ; END IF;
     IF UPDATING ('FIRST_NAME') AND NVL(:NEW.FIRST_NAME,-1) != NVL(:OLD.FIRST_NAME,-1)  THEN V_COLS_UPDATED:=V_COLS_UPDATED || 'FIRST_NAME' || ',' ; END IF;

END;


------------------------------
--------  Query for generating the "TRIGGER(BODY) SCRIPT"


    select 
    
           'IF UPDATING (''' || C.COLUMN_NAME ||
           ''') THEN V_COLS_UPDATED:=V_COLS_UPDATED || ''' || C.COLUMN_NAME ||
           ''' || '','' ; END IF;' IF_UPDATING,
           
           
           'IF UPDATING (''' || C.COLUMN_NAME || ''') AND NVL(:NEW.' ||
           C.COLUMN_NAME || ',-1) != NVL(:OLD.' || C.COLUMN_NAME ||
           ',-1)  THEN V_COLS_UPDATED:=V_COLS_UPDATED || ''' || C.COLUMN_NAME ||
           ''' || '','' ; END IF;' IF_UPDATING_AND_CHECK_VALUES
           
           
      from all_tab_columns c
     where c.owner='HR'
     and c.TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES'
     order by c.COLUMN_ID;
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So you can create triggers to Detect and LOG, detail of all changed columns!!!!

Comment: It would be great if you add a description to your answer!

Comment: Hi
I did it!
is the description OK?